# i've a list of values and I would like to iteratively append key-value pair to a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i've a list of values and I would like to iteratively append key-value pair to a python dictionary

lst = ['12233223','23232423','23453443']

i'm looking output like this:

new_list = [{'id':'12233223', 'new_id':'d2233223'},{'id':'13232423','new_id':'d3232423'}]

but I'm getting this

[{'id':13453443,'new_id':13453443},{'id':13453443,'new_id':13453443}]

Here is my code

```
lst = [{'id':'12233223'},{'id':'13232423',} {'id':'23453443'}]
d={}
new_list=[]
for each in lst:
    d['id']= each
    if len(each)==8 and each[0]==1:
    new_id = each.replace('1','d',1)
    d['new_id'] = new_id
    new_list.append(d)
```

same value is added to the list for two times

Comment: Dictionary keys must be unique. You're trying to create a dictionary where each key is identical. You need a different data structure. What do you want to do with `new_list`?

Comment: @Pines sorry my mistake. I'm looking for list of dictionaries. I've updated the code. Please check

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a dict with all keys bearing the same value. But you can have a list of dicts instead

```py
new_list = [{'id': each} for each in lst]
```

Comment: ..i've updated the script with one more dict value. please check

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension to go through your list of dictionaries with a nested `for` to get to the values.  Then apply the filter condition and build new dictionaries from the eligible dictionaries/values:

```
lst = [{'id':'12233223'},{'id':'13232423'}, {'id':'23453443'}]


new_list = [ {**each,'new_id':"d"+n[1:]} for each in lst 
             for n in each.values() if len(n)==8 and n[0]=='1' ]

print(new_list)
              
[{'id': '12233223', 'new_id': 'd2233223'}, 
 {'id': '13232423', 'new_id': 'd3232423'}]
```

If the dictionaries in `lst` have other keys, you can make the nested `for` more specific to obtain just the value of the 'id' keys:

```
new_list = [ {**each,'new_id':"d"+n[1:]} for each in lst 
             for n in [each['id']] if len(n)==8 and n[0]=='1' ]
```